# Accessing Azure SQL database using Ruby (TinyTds)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, azure-sql-database, tiny-tds

I am trying migrate data

- from an old database, that I can access through the Azure Interface,
- to a new postgres db, in a Ruby on Rails app

To try and access the Azure database, using SQL server authentication, I'm calling a service, following [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-ruby?view=azuresql)

`azure_export_service.rb`

```rb
require 'tiny_tds'
class AzureExportService
  attr_accessor :client

  def initialize
    self.client = TinyTds::Client.new(
      username: Rails.application.credentials.azure.username,
      password: Rails.application.credentials.azure.password,
      database: Rails.application.credentials.azure.database,
      host: Rails.application.credentials.azure.server,
      port: 1433,
      azure: true
    )
  end

  def call
    tsql = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Country];'
    result = client.execute(tsql)
    result.each do |row|
      puts row
    end
    result
  end
end
```

I keep getting this timeout error when I'm trying to open a connection

```
TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection timed out (<mydb>.database.windows.net)
```

The credentials I am using are the same ones Azure is providing in the database connection strings. I have tried running the Troubleshooting powershell script  provided by Microsoft, using those same credentials. It has no problem connecting to the server and database. It is however reporting "redirect conectivity" as failing (might this be the reason ?)

I tried added firewall rules to the Azure SQL Server to allow my IPv4 adress, but to no effect.

Could anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong ?

Thank you very much

**What I'm trying:**

Connecting to an azure SQL Database,
using Ruby (TinyTDS)

**Expecting:**

A successful connection

**What happenned:**

A Timeout error

```
TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection timed out (<mydb>.database.windows.net)
```